# How should I compensate for numerical inaccuracy in fixed-point multiplication?

Tags: error-propagation

I am experimenting with fixed point arithmetic.  I found [a library for doing fixed-point math using vectors of 32-bit integers](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/fp128-opencl-42102) .  At the end of the mulfpu (unsigned fixed point multiplication) function they "add 3 to compensate for the truncation".  I figure they didn't feel like performing a bunch of `mul_hi`s on the lower order terms just to get a couple of bits exactly right.

Is there a general formula for figuring out what the proper fudge factor is for various forms of fixed point multiplication?

When I make a variation of this logic that uses three 4-vectors of 16-bit unsigned ints (ushort4 a[3]) and compare the results to python's mpmath using extra bits of precision the average error seems to be 8 quantums (with a range of roughly 4-12).

If I use a different variation that uses three 2-vectors of 32-bit unsigned ints (uint2 a[3]) the average error appears to be 3.4 quantums (with a range of roughly 1-6)

All of this is muddied by the fact that I don't know if there are defects in my multiplication routines, or if there are dark corners in python's mpmath library.

Comment: Quoting from [the indirectly linked post](http://www.bealto.com/mp-mandelbrot_fp128-opencl.html): *Exactly computing the next word would require 7 additional 32-bit products to sum just to estimate the last 3 bits of the result. For speed reasons, I simply added 3, which is the mean value of the upcoming carry.*

Comment: But why is 3 "the mean value of the upcoming carry"?  And why do some of my experiments using a different data structure give me a mean value of 8?  I'm hoping for a theoretical basis explaining 3 -vs- 8 (and perhaps different values for different data structures)